# Combine multiple documentclasses; maintain page numbering and structure for TOC/TOF

Tags: table-of-contents, ieeetran, pdfpages, thesis, combine

I'm writing a thesis that includes two articles. The institution provided a style file for the thesis; the articles use `IEEEtran`. Furthermore, the used packages in each document may differ significantly.

**Desired Result:** a single PDF that contains the thesis and articles while maintaining each document's prescribed format and consistent page numbering. The PDF should also include a single *comprehensive* table of contents (TOC), table of figures (TOF), table of tables (TOT) and bibliography. This document document would be structured as follows:

- Front Matter (e.g. Title Page, TOC,TOF,TOT, Abstract)
- Introduction
- Article 1
- Article 2
- Conclusion
- Back Matter (e.g. Bibliography)

The `combine` package would not compile the document. The `pdfpages` package was able to build a single, combined document with consistent page numbering, but I am unable to produce the TOC/TOF/TOT/Bibliography. Can anyone provide a minimal example of a working solution?

Comment: If the articles have their own section information, etc. you can use the `pax` package with `pdflatex` or `lualatex` to include that information when the `pdfpages` package is used.

Comment: can you add informations about Bibliography? why this is a problem for `pdfpages`?

Comment: The bibliography in the back matter should include all references from all documents. I may be able to just whittle the *.bib file down to only those references that were cited and use the `\nocite{*}` command in the back matter, but the real challenge seems to be getting the TOC/TOF/TOT working.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\blinddocument
%-------------article1
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{title of article1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{title of section}
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{nice figure}
\addcontentsline{lot}{table}{small table}
\includepdf[pages=1-2,pagecommand={bla}]{myfile2.pdf}
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{title of section}
\includepdf[pages=3-,pagecommand={bla}]{myfile2.pdf}
\addcontentsline{lot}{table}{second table}
%-------------article2
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{title of article2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{title of section}
\includepdf[pages=1-3,pagecommand={bla}]{myfile3.pdf}
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{title of section}
\includepdf[pages=4-,pagecommand={bla}]{myfile3.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the *bodies* of the documents, put them into separate files, which you `\input{...}` (or `\include{...}`, if separate chapters, which start new pages) from the main file.

Even if it starts as a collage of articles-each-with-it's-own-format, sooner or later you will start working on getting uniform look-and-feel.